# highcharts help - stuck with chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to do the following chart https://postimg.cc/n981pM1y with Highcharts. I have done this example https://jsfiddle.net/w9vncpk0/17/ but I can't get each series to be grouped on the same line. I started thinking that it is not possible to do it this way but I would like another opinion `c`

Comment: Please note: A [mre] that shows your issue is supposed to be included _directly_ within your question; please do not just dump the whole thing onto an external platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chart can be easily created with Highcharts. You need to only use `stacking` logic.

For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Apagado',
      id: 'Apagado',
      color: 'red',
      stack: 'LTP 3569',
      data: [
        [0, 2],
        [1, 2]
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Moderando',
      id: 'Moderando',
      color: 'yellow',
      stack: 'LTP 3569',
      data: [
        [0, 2],
        [1, 3]

      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Conduciendo',
      id: 'Conduciendo',
      color: 'green',
      stack: 'LTP 3569',
      data: [
        [0, 23],
        [1, 20]

      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Apagado',
      color: 'red',
      linkedTo: 'Apagado',
      stack: 'LTP 3570',
      data: [
        [0, 4],
        [1, 5]
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Moderando',
      color: 'yellow',
      linkedTo: 'Moderando',
      stack: 'LTP 3570',
      data: [
        [0, 7],
        [1, 5]

      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Conduciendo',
      color: 'green',
      stack: 'LTP 3570',
      linkedTo: 'Conduciendo',
      data: [
        [0, 2],
        [1, 1]
      ]
    }
  ]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ht53g8d6/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/stacking-charts